# bash find returning path with leading '.' how can I eliminate this character from return string?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running the following line from the apache logs directory to move older (previously zipped) logs to a storage location:

```
/usr/local/apache2.2/logs$ find . -name '*.gz' -exec cp {} /home/itadmin/temp4{} \;
```

The result is slightly off due to the '.' included in the returned file path:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/home/itadmin/temp4./default/error/error.1315029600.gz': No such file or directory
```

Is there a simple way to eliminate the '.' from the file path while still utilizing the above command as closely as possible to the way it's written now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy all files in one invocation of `cp` like this:

```
$ find . -name '*.gz' -exec cp --target-directory=/home/itadmin/temp4 {} +
```

Or just add a slash to your original command:

```
/usr/local/apache2.2/logs$ find . -name '*.gz' -exec cp {} /home/itadmin/temp4/{} \;
```

Comment: Thanks - that eliminated the error, but now when I run it no files are moved? I tried it with the '+' directly appended to the move path and also with a space following the move path? This is how i tried it, so it may be user incompetence...find . -name '*.gz' -exec cp {} /home/itadmin/temp4 + \;

Comment: Replace `cp` with `mv` if you want to move.

Comment: ahhh the slash...I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thanks Maxim, that did it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

I often use

```
find * -name ...
```

It's not exactly equivalent; it skips anything in the current directory whose name starts with `.`.  That's ok if you don't have, or don't care about, any such files or directories.  And it's great if you specifically want to skip them (e.g., `.git`).

Or you can filter the output of `find`.  For example (not tested)

```
find . -name ... | sed 's/^\.\/\(.\)/\1/'
```

It searches for, and leaves in place, a single character following `./` to avoid mangling the line consisting of just `./` (not needed if you have `-type f`).  If you're going to use that, consider adding the filter as a command in your ~/bin directory.

Answer (score -1):

Don't specify the `.` directory explicitely.

```
/usr/local/apache2.2/logs$ find -name '*.gz' -exec cp {} /home/itadmin/temp4/{} \;
```

Comment: Doesn't `find` require at least one path as the first argument?

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin: No. At least not on GNU/Linux `find`.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin: But I'm wrong in the sense that the `.` is implied if no other directory in given as parameter, and it appear anyway in the output. :-(

Comment: Thanks Didier, as usual I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using name, use print0, which will correctly handle full pathnames and files with spaces or other unusual characters. Also, you need to wrap `{}` in single quotes to prevent shell interpretation.

`find . -print0 '*.gz' -exec cp '{}' '/home/itadmin/temp4{}' \;`